# Name of largest row value

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, formula

I have an Excel table that lists various projects from which I would like to return the name of the largest project, based on certain criteria.  This is the table structure:

```
Project Title (A); Category (B); Completed Year (C); Dollar Amount(D)
```

The array formula below will give me the largest ranking item based on that criteria. However when I try to look up `column A`, it won't work properly with duplicates, like many zero dollar projects:

```
{(LARGE(IF($B$2:$B$1000="Services",IF(YEAR($C$2:$C$1000)=2015,$D$2:$D$1000,""),"‌​"),1)}
```

Comment: Are you sure you haven't typoed your formula? How can an entry of "Services" in column B also result in a value of 2015 when the YEAR function is applied to it?

Comment: Yup - that was a typo on my part onto the website. slimming down the example to only include appropriate columns: {(LARGE(IF($B$2:$B$1000="Services",IF(YEAR($C$2:$C$1000)=2015,$D$2:$D$1000,""),""),1)}

Comment: fwiw, in a nested `IF` type array formula, you don't need the FALSE values. e.g. `... ,""),"‌​"),1)` could just as easily be `... )),1)`.

Comment: Are there any blanks in column D? Are all values in that column non-negative?

Comment: Yes, all values in D are non negative.

Comment: @Jeeped you're right you don't need the FALSE values, but if you dont place them the formula defaults to outputting a FALSE Boolean data type. That doesn't necessarily works for every application, specifically this one.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the following array formula:

```
{=(LARGE(IF($B$2:$B$1000="Services",1,0)*IF(YEAR($C$2:$C$1000)=2015,1,0)*$D$2:$D$1000,1))}
```

I'm using the `IF`'s to generate arrays with 1 for each line that conform to each criteria. Then multiplying them only maintains a 1 for each line that meets both. Finally multiply that array by an array of your target values to perpetuate only the relevant ones for comparison by `LARGE`. Regards,

Regards,

Comment: For some reason I am getting an #Value error.  Would the proposed formula be: {=(LARGE(IF($B$2:$B$1000="Services",1,0)*IF(YEAR($C$2:$C$1000)=2015,1,0)*$D$2:$D$1000,1))*(A2:A1000)}

Comment: Are you inputting the formula as an array? I get the same when I input it as a regular formula but array formula works. If it is inputted correctly can you run "Evaluate Formula" and step through the calculations to see where the  `#VALUE` is appearing.

Comment: PLEASE! Everyone STOP putting braces into sample formulas. Excel wraps a formula with braces when entered as an **array formula** with [Ctrl]+Shift]+[Enter] (aka CSE). You cannot even copy those braces from the formula bar; you have to type them in yourself and it does nothing but confuse the issue at hand when they are added. Put a short note in the answer or question that it is an array formula and requires [Ctrl]+Shift]+[Enter] to be entered properly.

Comment: Nbayly, I evaluated the formula and I believe that the error is coming because it is multiplying s number by a string.  Also, the string (Project Title) that it is pulling is not the correct one.

Comment: @Jeeped PLEASE STOP FROM STOPPING PEOPLE IN CAPS!!! Sorry, had to be said! I usually do both by adding the bracket and noting how it is entered. This time around I did not because the OP had stated specifically from their posting that it was an array formula and had included that braces themselves. I don't think it's a unfair stretch to assume that they would understand the implications. Either way I encourage to anyone who reads this posting and doesn't understand array formulas to google the concept.

Comment: @user3692794 As the 2 `IF`'s only output either 1 or 0 the only place that strings would come from would be the `D` column which from your posting I was assuming the range where your values are placed. Is that not the case? Again I have to ask, have you inputted the formula without the brackets (as Jeeped mentioned) and then pressing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` to make into an Array Formula?